# Why doesn't my function await the end of ForEachAsync?

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, .net-core, iasyncenumerable

I'm trying to fill my model with data that I get from an asynchronous operation to my database. The problem is that the function returns the View (without the completed model), despite my await call.

I have tried to put a timer (I know that is not the solution), to be sure that the problem come from the asynchronous, I have also tried to put on comment some part of code inside my `ForEachAsync`, but it doesn't seem to help.

I get a list of project, that I fill with some additional information, finally, I assign my object to my model then return the View

```
public async Task<IActionResult> newProjetList(int GestionaireId, int VilleId)
{
    ProjetListModel model = new ProjetListModel();
    ProjetService projetService = new ProjetService(connectionString);
    UserServices userServices = new UserServices(connectionString);
    AvancementService avancementService = new AvancementService(connectionString);
    VilleService villeService = new VilleService(connectionString);
    List<Projet> projets = await projetService.NewProjetLine(GestionaireId, VilleId);

    await projets.ToAsyncEnumerable().ForEachAsync(async p =>
    {
        int villeId = await villeService.getVilleIdByProjetId(p.ProjetId);
        Ville ville = await villeService.GetById(villeId);
        p.Ville = ville.VilleLabel;
        p.GestionnaireProjet = await userServices.GetNameById(p.GestionnaireProjetId ?? 0);
        await p.SousProjet.ToAsyncEnumerable().ForEachAsync(async sp =>
         {
             sp.Avancement = await avancementService.GetLabelById(sp.AvancementId);
         });
    });
    model.projets = projets;
    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return View("ProjetList", model);
}
```

I expected an output with the missing information (here are the 'ville', 'gestionnairesProjet' and 'Avancement'

Comment: can I ask a question: *why* are you doing `.ToAsyncEnumerable().ForEachAsync` ? that just seems like a *really inefficient* way of doing `foreach(var project in projects) {...}` ? It doesn't add anything that I can see...

Comment: Did you read the [docs about ToAsyncEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.query.internal.asynclinqoperatorprovider.toasyncenumerable?view=efcore-2.1)?

Comment: @MarcGravell It makes things worse because the loop has an `await` to fetch the next item. I think OP misunderstood what `ForEachAsync` does. It doesn't let you aggregate a bunch of tasks. Rather it lets you iterate over an async collection (one where you have to `await iterator.MoveNext()`.) As noted in the answer below, what OP really wants is `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: @RaymondChen the per-item await isn't terrible - it is a value-task that will be already completed in this case. No major overhead added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForEachAsync` only takes an `Action<...>`, not a `Func<..., Task>`, so the `async` lambda your code is passing to `ForEachAsync` is becoming an [`async void` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). One of the primary reasons `async void` should be avoided is that it's not easy to determine when the method completes - and in fact, in this case, there is nothing ensuring that it will complete before sending the response.

I recommend doing what Marc suggested and just using `foreach`:

```
List<Projet> projets = await projetService.NewProjetLine(GestionaireId, VilleId);

foreach (var p in projects)
{
  int villeId = await villeService.getVilleIdByProjetId(p.ProjetId);
  Ville ville = await villeService.GetById(villeId);
  p.Ville = ville.VilleLabel;
  p.GestionnaireProjet = await userServices.GetNameById(p.GestionnaireProjetId ?? 0);
  foreach (var sp in p.SousProject)
  {
    sp.Avancement = await avancementService.GetLabelById(sp.AvancementId);
  }
}
model.projets = projets;
```

Or, if you want to use asynchronous concurrency, you can make use of `Task.WhenAll`:

```
List<Projet> projets = await projetService.NewProjetLine(GestionaireId, VilleId);

await Task.WhenAll(projects.Select(async p =>
{
  int villeId = await villeService.getVilleIdByProjetId(p.ProjetId);
  Ville ville = await villeService.GetById(villeId);
  p.Ville = ville.VilleLabel;
  p.GestionnaireProjet = await userServices.GetNameById(p.GestionnaireProjetId ?? 0);
  await Task.WhenAll(p.SousProject.Select(async sp =>
  {
    sp.Avancement = await avancementService.GetLabelById(sp.AvancementId);
  });
});
model.projets = projets;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use `ForEachAwaitAsync` instead of `ForEachAsync`**

**Explanation**: `ForEachAsync` can't wait since it is simply a multi-threaded execution of your loop (accepts `Action`). In fact you might have received a compiler warning by using `async` for your lambda return, because you intend to assign a `Task` to a `void` (unused)

`ForEachAwaitAsync` will wait because it accepts a `Func<Task>` and internally also awaits / asyncs accordingly.

For curious minds, you can see the source code here: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ForEach.cs mentioned as `ForEachAwaitAsyncCore` and `ForEachAsync`